# I keep getting "Non-exhaustive patterns in function isPermutation" when I have ALL possible cases?

Tags: haskell, permutation

I am trying to do create a function that uses two lists. For some reason, when I pass:

isPermutation [] [], or [] [1,2,3] or [1,2,3] []   - 
**I get Non-exhaustive patterns in function isPermutation**

```
isPermutation :: (Eq a)=>[a]->[a]->Bool
**isPermutaiton** [] [] = True
**isPermutaiton** [] ys = False
**isPermutation** xs [] = False
isPermutation (x:xs) (ys) = True
```

I cannot figure out why am I getting this since I am covering all cases!

**UPDATE**
**Thanks to Chris Taylor : - It was a simple typo. I had misspelled one of my function names "isPermutaiton" instead of "isPermutation" **

**Be careful on your spelling since Haskell won't recognize that you are meaning the same function(duh) or that you are "declaring" 2 different functions with cases meshed up.**

Comment: If you display code with a problem, and somebody gives you the solution, don't edit it to remove the error.  Add an update to explain the error and (if you like) an example of how the fixed code would look.  But leave the original error in place, so people can learn properly from your question.

Comment: Fully noted. Added explanation as well.

Comment: It would be helpful if there was a warning for when you give a function a type signature that is separated from its implementation, as I've been bitten by this a couple of times in the past. Does anyone know if there's an option to turn a warning like this on?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a typo in your second and third lines -- `isPermutaiton` instead of `isPermutation`.

You have effectively defined

```
foo [] [] = True       -- both arguments empty
foo [] ys = False      -- first argument empty, second argument anything

bar  xs    [] = False  -- second argument empty, first argument anything
bar (x:xs) ys = True   -- first argument at least one element, second anything
```

so whenever you call `foo` (i.e. `isPermutaiton`) with a non-empty first argument you will get an error, and whenever you call `bar` (i.e. `isPermutation`) with an empty first argument and a non-empty second argument you will get an error.